# Excel equivalent keyboard shortcut to CTRL+D for filling in columns selected columns with the same values to the left or to the right?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts

I don't always use Excel, but when I do, I find the need to fill duplicate values between columns that I have selected and not just values below the currently selected cell.

Is there an equivalent keyboard shortcut to do this?

Without copying and pasting.

Comment: Copy Ctrl+C   and Paste Ctrl+V. Excel shortcuts since Excel inception.

Comment: Do Ctrl+R for Fill Right work for you? I'm afraid there is no hotkey for Fill Left. But you can select a range, enter the desired value and complete the input with Ctrl+Enter.

Comment: Continuous or regularly spaced?

Comment: @Lee Continuous.